# IntelliJ 14 Unable to generate JavaFX exe

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am trying to package an app to an exe file, (including java8, so it is self contained). The app needs to run on any machine even if java is not installed.

Here is a screenshot of my settings:

[image]

[image]

I get this as an error:

```
Error:Java FX Packager: 
BUILD FAILED
/home/foo/.IntelliJIdea14/system/compile-server/_temp_/build0.xml:11: 
Total time: 0 seconds
Error:Java FX Packager: Buildfile: /home/foo/.IntelliJIdea14/system/compile-server/_temp_/build0.xml
build artifact:
Error:Java FX Packager: fx:deploy task has failed.
```

Now what am I supposed to get from this error ?

How can I fix this and get my app executable?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  I'm having the exact same issue with IntelliJ 15.  Worse, its for a project that did build, then I had the IDE generate ant build files, which didn't work, removed the generated build files, so I'm back to the default IDE building, and still am getting the error.  The file "build0.xml" does not exist in my case, even though the IDE shows line 11 for an error.  Instead of the file build0.xml in folder "_temp_", there's an empty folder named "jna--1422087353".